# jquery datepicker is not a function

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I'm getting a TypeError that datepicker is not a function.  I've included the jquery min file and the jquery ui min file:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, 'js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQueryUI, 'js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js')}" />
```

Here is the how I'm calling datepicker:

```
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$('[id$=tradeStartDateFilter]').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: make sure your your path to jquery  ui file is correct and loaded.

Comment: I checked and double checked the path and it is correct.  How can I check if it is actually loading?

Comment: Open the dev tools for your browser (F12) and go to the network tab, then refresh the page. It should show you all resources it attempts to load, and you can see any errors.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the network tab. That is good to know.  If I can ask one more additional question.  Is there a way to get the datepicker to format the input field when the page is refreshed via an Ajax postback?  The date format comes back like this: Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT 2013.  I would have thought it would have caught it on the post back, but is changes to the GMT format.